# i want to make a 3D moving Box using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angularjs, three.js, stimulusjs

I am looking for some advises or help regarding 3d Moving box in react something like this https://packlane.com/customize/mailer-box?quantity=250&sub_type=standard
If anyone can help it would mean a lot.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use Blender to export animation. then use THREE.js to display it on a web browser (threejs works with React pretty well)

Here is a good tutorial that can give you a better idea: https://unboring.net/workflows/animation.html